# how store text files from directory in 2d arrays in python?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, file, store, words

I want store my files from a folder in 2d arrays it means:words are my columns and for each file there is on row. this is my code but words store in array wrongly,what should I do?
for example:
file 1:hello python
file 2:bye c++
I expect in row 1 store hello in column 1 and python in column 2 and in row 2 store bye in column 1 and c++ in column 2

```
j=0
i=0
adress=""
import os, sys

# Open a file
path = 'E:/corpus'   
dirs = os.listdir( path )

# This would print all the files and directories      
for files in dirs:
    print files
    j=0
    i=i+1
    my=""

    adress='E:/corpus/'+files
    with open(adress, 'r') as myfile:
        for myline in myfile:
            for word in myline.split(" "):
                my=my+" "+word

    data=my.split(" ")
    for mydata in data:
        mylist[i][j]=mydata
        j=j+1
```

Comment: Use a dictionary instead. It will be much easier to manage than a multi dimension list.

Comment: what is the output you expect ?

Comment: @Setop I have one folder with 300 text files I want store the words of files in 2d array, it means in my 2d array I expect for each file one row that words store in columns:like:file 1:hello python,file 2:bye c++,i expect in row one store hello in column one and python in column two and in row two store bye in column one and c++ in column two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer finally,this cod store 100 txt file form a folder in 100 rows of an array and the words of each file are columns of this array.

```
n=100
mylist=[]
tempstring=""
row=0


import os, sys

# Open a file
path = 'E:\corpus'   
dirs = os.listdir( path )

# This would print all the files and directories      
for files in dirs:


    print files


    adress='E:/corpus/'+files
    with open(adress, 'r') as myfile:
        for myline in myfile:
            for word in myline.split(" "):

                tempstring=tempstring+" "+word

    a=0
    temparray=tempstring.split(" ")
    for i in xrange(row,row+1):


        mylist.append([])

        for data in temparray:

            mylist[i].append(data)
            a=a+1
    if(a==len(temparray)):
        row=row+1
        tempstring=""
```